# create and restore a mysql db using a setup project (installer) in VS.Net

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, installation, setup-project, restore

What is the best practice for creating an installer for a winform application.

The application is supposed to install the following without connecting to internet.

- .Net Framework 3.5sp1
- MySQL Server
- My SQL Connector
- Restore Mysql db
- Update Config file with the MySQL uname/pwd.

I have all the msi files for installing the above mentioned items. But am wondering about the best practice to create the installer.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Hi I came up with a similar situation. Firstly you should have .NET framework offline installer which can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=992cffcb-f8ce-41d9-8bd6-31f3e216285c. I assume you are using visual studio installer. There are couple of choices but I prefer to copy the offline .NET installer to the setup projects output directory and from requirements on target machine tab I set the install URL property of .NET framework the exact name of offline setup file. As described in the figure. [image: .net install URL]

So the installer does not try to connect to a remote computer to download .NET framework and install it however I think it is more appropriate that it connects to a Microsoft server and installs it. Anyways the next step is to configure the MySQL server. MySQL is really generous for me since they support a fully documented noinstall files. You can find the document here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-install-archive.html

Using a noinstall zip archive you can copy the dbengine core files to any folder on the clint machine. And change the configuration parameters of MySQL. You can name the MySQL service anything you want. Start the the service and create tables. You can do all of this stuff from custom actions tab of the setup project choosing the appropriate script files or you can write code for it. The beautiful thing is that your customer does not need to know that he/she is installing a database engine on the target machine. I hope this helps. Thanks.